# Selenium.WebDriver 2.32.1 C# - Wait untill LOADING DIV is hidden after Page Load

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am really sorry if this question has already been asked/answered. but I could not find it.

Please excuse my ignorance as I am new to WebDriver.

When the page is initially loads, it displays a LOADING DIV untill all the data is loaded. How can I wait until this div is hidden before I proceed with other actions on page elements?

I am trying to know as follows:

```
    public static void waitForPageLoad(string ID, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.Id(ID));
        });
    }
```

I pass the Id of SOME OTHER ELEMENT to this function which I will use when the LOADING DIV disappears. It returns the wrong result as the element by ID is actually present/loaded but is behind the grey DIV that shows "Loading... Please wait" message. So this does not work. I would like to know when that LOADING div disappears.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By waiting on a `bool` value instead of `IWebElement`, the .NET `WebDriverWait` class will wait until a value of `true` is returned. Given that, how about trying something like the following:

```
public static void WaitForElementToNotExist(string ID, IWebDriver driver)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
    {
        try
        {
            // If the find succeeds, the element exists, and
            // we want the element to *not* exist, so we want
            // to return true when the find throws an exception.
            IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.Id(ID));
            return false;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this is the appropriate pattern if the element you're looking for is actually removed from the DOM. If, on the other hand, the "waiting" element is always present in the DOM, but just made visible/invisible as required by the JavaScript framework your app is using, then the code is a little simpler, and looks something like this:

```
public static void WaitForElementInvisible(string ID, IWebDriver driver)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
    {
        try
        {
            IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.Id(ID));
            return !element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            // If the find fails, the element exists, and
            // by definition, cannot then be visible.
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks . i will give it a try .. but will this not always return FALSE? as they Loading Div is just hidden and is present on the page

Comment: You're absolutely right. Your original question wasn't clear whether the loading div "disappearing" meant that it was removed from the DOM, or just made invisible. I've edited my response to show an example of the visible/invisible case.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve my problem of NoSuchElementException that I was getting in my attempt at this solution.  I had one difference, I am returning the result of the wait as a boolean. As such, just add a return in front of the wait.Until command. public static bool WaitForElementNotVisible(...) { ... return wait.Until<bool>(...);}