# unable to click on span element with .NET WebDriver but able with Selenium IDE

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two peaces of code - one for Selenium WebDriver and another for Selenium IDE:

This one fails to find an element and click it:

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            FirefoxProfile ffP = new FirefoxProfile();
            ffP.EnableNativeEvents = true;
            IWebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver(ffP);
            dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://cgqakiev.fg.local/ropesgray");
            dr.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("admin");
            dr.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("pass2app");
            dr.FindElement(By.Id("loginSubmit")).Click();

            var CC = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Conflict Check')]"));
            CC.Click(); 
        }
    }
}
```

While this one from Selenium IDE works ok:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[contains(text(), 'Conflict Check')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

What to do to click in WebDriver? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Well how does the page differ? Do you need to click on something to get that element to appear?

Comment: well. the page does not differ at all. but, being a genius that I am - i've already found an answer to my question. still thank you!

Comment: That's great, usually when that happens you should answer your own question here, so if someone else comes across your question, they have that idea to try out.

Comment: Have you tried exporting it from the Selenium IDE in the format that you need?

Answer (score 0):

As Arran suggested: the problem was that the clicking occurred before the page got fully loaded (WebDriver problem) while with selenium IDE i had the application opened and loaded already so there was what to click already. so this is my stupidity)

then the solution i've found is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283166/1922804

i had a 'loading...' progress bar that i needed to disappear before proceeding with test execution.